# Bootstrap navbar background colour not overriding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am simply trying to override the default colour of the default navbar using bootstrap, which I have done many times before, but it simply keeps displaying the default colour and I was wondering if I have done something stupid that someone else may be able to spot?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/site.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #900000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the background image was causing an issue, try just setting only the main background attribute:

```
.navbar-default {
  background: #900000;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work, although I am not using a background image - why does this need to be background instead of background-color?

Comment: Hi James, I think its down to bootstrap using background-image for a linear gradiant. Just setting background-color may not override it fully as its still being used on the default CSS. Having the main attribute is a more effective way of overriding all the background properties in one declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this is to use parent / child selectors to override BootStrap's styling as follows:

I assume you can use an element further up the tree:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Then target it as follows:

```
.wrapper .navbar-default {
    background-color: #900000;
    background-image: none;
}
```

This works due to the law of specificity: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Also make sure your custom CSS file is loaded AFTER BootStrap's...

EDIT: if your page has got a class appended to the `<body>` tag:

```
<body class="standard">
```

You could even use that...

```
.standard .navbar-default {
        background-color: #900000;
        background-image: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is exactly my issue, there is no parent up the tree, the navbar-default is the highest parent and also, as you can see, my custom CSS file is indeed, loaded after Bootstrap.

Comment: You can just use the body as the parent then: `body .navbar-default { }`... BootStrap doesn't use a parent / child in this particular case as you know so this will override it...

Answer (score 0):

Just change your class

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #900000 !important;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #900000 !impotant;
}
```